# /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error MSB6006: "strip" exited with code 1

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, mono

I try to debug my xamarin ios app on real ios device (ipad mini 2 ios 11.1.2). And got this message when build:

> "strip" exited whis code 1 (MSB6006).
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error MSB6006: "strip" exited with code 1. (MSB6006)

I do this on MacOS Sierra (VMware) by Visual studio 2017 for MAC.
What can I do to resolve this error

Comment: Enable MSBuild's diagnostic level logging for more details

Comment: I Don't know how to do this. Please explain. Visual studio 2017 for MAC

Comment: Sorry. I found decision by myself.